# Avoid Null value exception in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm trying to filter a DataTable using LINQ

```
DataTable DT=new DataTable();
DT = PinDicDAO.GetContractPOVD().AsEnumerable().Where(r => (r.Field<string>("ContractPOReference").ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper())) || (r.Field<string>("ContractPO").ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper())) ||
                                   (r.Field<string>("ContractPOTitle").ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper())) || (r.Field<string>("Address").ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper()))
                                   ).AsDataView().ToTable();
```

Query works fine. But when some fields have NULL values it gives a Exception.

```
"Object Reference Not set to an instance of object"
```

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: Just add null checks where you suspect them. for example `r.Field<string>("ContractPOReference != null ...`

Answer (score 1):

Check for nulls before you try to use it. You'd better use the linq keywords so you can use let and make it more readable:

```
var query = from r in PinDicDAO.GetContractPOVD().AsEnumerable()
                        let ContractPOReference = r.Field<string>("ContractPOReference")
                        let ContractPO = r.Field<string>("ContractPO")
                        let ContractPOTitle = r.Field<string>("ContractPOTitle")
                        let Address = r.Field<string>("Address")
                        where (ContractPOReference != null && ContractPOReference.ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper())) ||
                           (ContractPO != null && ContractPO.ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper())) ||
                           (ContractPOTitle != null && ContractPOTitle.ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper())) ||
                           (Address != null && Address.ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper()))
                        select r;

            DT = query.AsDataView().ToTable();
```

Comment: Exception occurred "Can not create DataView after using projection".On line DT = query.AsDataView().ToTable();

Comment: You can do this also with linq methods like r.Field<string>("ContractPOReference") != null && r.Field<string>("ContractPOReference").ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper()))